# How to split long strings in PhpStorm / IDEA when use auto-formatting

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have a long string like the one below, that contains few variables

```php
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, $var1 adipiscing elit. Curabitur sed $var2 nunc. Nunc elementum in felis et venenatis. $var3 quis finibus sem, consectetur ornare leo. "
```

I want this line to be broken into a few lines when I format it automatically (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>).

Comment: Definitely not possible for PHP. There is an intention to do string split at the caret position (`Alt+Enter` --> `Split string into two strings and concatenation`) .. but that's about it (and it seem to work only one per string). Perhaps some custom plugin (those that I use (String Manipulation mainly) do not offer this).